# How to create an Animation on a Card?

Tags: flutter

i have a Card where a Arrow rotates when i click on the card. Then i get a new Card below the Card i clicked. Now i wanted, that the second Card opens with an Animation. Only the height should be animated. How can i do this?

Code from the Arrow:

```
new InkWell(
              child: new Card(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new  ListTile(
                      title: new Text("Notfallmanagement", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,),),
                      trailing: new Transform.rotate(
                        angle: _rotateArrowController.value * PI,
                        child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Colors.orange, size: 50.0,),
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                  _notfall = !_notfall;
                  if(_rotateArrowController.isCompleted){
                    _rotateArrowController.reverse();
                    _cardAnimationController.reverse();
                  } else {
                    _rotateArrowController.forward();
                    _cardAnimationController.forward();
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
```

Code for the second Card:

```
return new Card(
        color: Colors.white70,
        child: new Container(
          height: _cardAnimation.value,

//some other Code
        ),
      );
```

In the Container is a lot of other Widgets and so the height isnt const.
How can i get the height of the card to the animation?